# Error in connecting to Windows EC2 instance via Session Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

I followed Every step in the image

Changed IAM instance profile

Installed -

- SSM Agent
- Command line interface v2
- EC2 configservice

Comment: Are you sure the agent is running in the ec2?

Comment: Did you assign appropriate permissions to the IAM Role that is associated with the EC2 instance? It requires `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` permissions to connect to the AWS Systems Manager service to 'register' the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SSH Client PUTTY in your Windows. I am not sure about connecting with Session Manager. However, you can easily connect via PUTTY on Port 22. In EC2 security group you have to allow your IP to connect over Port number 22.

If you are downloading PEM file from AWS EC2 creation, use PuttyGen to create a PPK file.